# Is there a benefit to a pilot/aviator having an FCC GROL license?

Tags: pilots, student-pilot

I am an avionics technician (c-130) in the USAF and plan on learning to fly helicopters when I separate in about a year.

I have debated whether or not to pursue a [GROL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_radiotelephone_operator_license) or possibly [A&P](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aircraft_maintenance_technician).  From what I know, these are generally intended for maintainers/technicians rather than aviators.

That said, would there be any benefit to having a GROL or related license for an aspiring helicopter pilot?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no tangible benefit to having a GROL in getting a pilots license of any kind as getting the license generally confers the right to use aircraft radios. In some places you need to get an RT license for aviation as a separate test, however that's pretty minimal. A GROL is only good for repairing, maintaining, and running certain types of radio stations.

An A&P will let you work on airplanes, but it also does not help get a license. An A&P will give you insights into how an airplane works, but you can get those insights without an A&P. Having an A&P and a pilots license might be a different story if you plan to work in remote locations where being able to fix your aircraft when it breaks is useful. It won't help you get a flying job in most places.

Answer (score 0):

The only FCC license that you might need is the [restricted radiotelephone operator permit (RR)](http://wireless.fcc.gov/commoperators/index.htm?job=rr).  There is no test for the permit but there is a fee.  You'll only need the permit if you intend to fly outside of the united states and communicate with foreign ATC.

Answer (score 0):

> From what I know, these are generally intended for
>   maintainers/technicians rather than aviators.

Correct, an A&P will not help you get a pilots license (aside from maybe gaining a better understanding of how the internals work).

> That said, would there be any benefit to having a GROL or related
>   license for an aspiring helicopter pilot?

This is a bit of a different question, to which the answer may be yes, in the sense that an A&P cert can be useful if you are involved in aviation. An A&P could be very valuable to you as an aviator in general. First off if you intend on owning a helicopter you will be able to undercut some of the costs by doing work yourself. As mentioned if you intend on flying in remote places being able to work on your own bird can literally save your life. If you are looking to fly professionally you can always make money on the side doing A&P work (its a pretty high paying profession). I have no idea if it has any bearing but there is a chance it will lower your insurance premiums as well (generally the more certifications you have the lower your insurance